# Get the last item for a many-to-many relation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, limit

I have 3 tables: `categories`, `items` and `items_categories`. It's a many-to-many relation. The structure of this tables is the next:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)

CREATE TABLE `items_categories` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `thumb` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)
```

I've indexes but I removed because aren't needed for this example.

I need a query that returns me all categories joined with the **last item** for each of it and that it's NOT repeated. As items can have many categories, say that item #300 (the latest) has categories #1 and #2 in the final results category #1 and #2 will be joined with different items.

For now I have this query but it doesn't do what I exactly want:

```
SELECT category_id, c.name, c.slug, item_id, i.name, i.thumb
FROM   items_categories AS ic
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = ic.category_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM   items ORDER  BY id DESC) AS i ON i.id = ic.item_id
GROUP  BY c.id
ORDER  BY c.id ASC
```

It returns me duplicated results and it returns the first item and not the last.

Dummy data: http://pastebin.com/D75tr4Ry

How I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: Looks quite tricky for a single query. You don't want to do it in a stored procedure or via code?

Comment: @TJ probably the duplicated thing is tricky, no? It can be done, at least, the join with last item easily? Via code will be to run a query for each category?

Comment: Yes, the duplicated part. Yes, join with last can be done. See this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45563/3 (I hope I am correct)

Comment: mmm this kind of subquery won't give problems with like 1M items and 2.5M relations items_categories?

Comment: You are right, it will be slow. Check this updated query (the second one) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45563/26 [It should run okay if the number of categories is not huge.] Try explain on both the queries.

Comment: How do you define 'last item' (or, for that matter 'first item'?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add **limit** in subquery. After using limit you can get all categories for last  item.

Try this :

```
SELECT category_id, c.name, c.slug, item_id, i.name, i.thumb 
FROM items_categories AS ic 
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON ic.category_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS i ON ic.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```